# How to know if my user is an active directory user

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to know if my user is an active directory account n throught domain ,login and password.
I test this function :

```
public void ValidateCredentials(string sUserName, string sPassword)
    {
        PrincipalContext adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        using (adContext)
        {
           bool tes= adContext.ValidateCredentials(sUserName, sPassword);
        }
    }
```

but i always return true even the domain,users and password are fault.

Comment: i got this even the domain was rang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternately, you can try this...

```
try
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword);

    using (var connection = new LdapConnection(domainName))
    {
        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Kerberos 
        connection.Bind(credentials);
    }

    return true;
}
catch
{
    //handle errors as you see fit
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this code to do that via P/Invoke and I've never had any problems with it:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

public enum LogonType
{
    Interactive = 2,
    Network = 3,
    Batch = 4,
    Service = 5,
    Unlock = 7,
    NetworkClearText = 8,
    NewCredentials = 9,
}

public enum LogonProvider
{
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
}

public static bool LdapAuthentication(string domain, string user, string password, Configurator cfg)
{
    try
    {
        LogonType lt = LogonType.Network;

        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        return (LogonUser(user, domain, password, (int)lt, (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out token));
    }
    catch
    {
        return (false);
    }
}
```

If you still have some problems, maybe you can try to change the `LogonType`.

Please mark this answer as accepted if it responds to your question.

Comment: thanks Morix Dev, I used connection.Bind(credentials);

Comment: You're welcome... consider that I switched to P/Invoke solution after having used @codingChris approach in the past, because in at least one situation I had problem in authenticating domain users with that approach (depending on how the domain is configured? could it be?)... instead my solution *seems* to work in all cases...